# How should I find the base resistance when a common-emitter amplifier is at its Q point?

Tags: resistors, bjt, kirchhoffs-laws

Using this circuit diagram and the characteristics below, I've been asked to determine Rb when Ib at the Q point is 30 micro amps.
[image]

I've tried solving this problem in two different ways: first, KVL, and by finding the slope of two points on the input characteristics (specifically (0.6 V, 30 micro Amps) and (1.0 V, 0 amps)) and setting that to -1/Rb. I get two different answers when I work these problems out (13.3 k Ohms w/ KVL, 20 K by finding the slope and equaling it -1/Rb). Which is the correct way  to do this?

Comment: Do you want \$R_b\$ (the equivalent DC resistance) or \$r_b\$, the differential resistance that will be a parameter of the ac model for small perturbations around the operating point?

Comment: Or do you want \$\rm{R_B}\$, the value of one of the components on the schematic?

Comment: \$\rm{R_B}\$, the value of component in the schematic when the the current passing through is at 30 micro amps, the amplifier's Q point (meaning Vin from the signal would be zero and DC analysis can be used)

Comment: I'm guessing he means the RB resistor value since it is the only unknown in the schematic.

Comment: @Trevor yes \$\rm{R_B}\$

Comment: Your 13.3K method gave you the right answer.

Comment: Vbe=0.6V@30uA thus (1-0.6V)/30uA=Rb

Comment: Thanks so much for y'alls help.. also @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, that a long time to be in EE. Glad the vets are looking out for us still in school

Comment: .........De nada

Answer (score 1):

Apply KVL around the loop with the 1 V supply, RB, and the b-e junction. You know the current, you know (from your chart) what \$v_{be}\$ is with that current. Now use ohm's law to figure out what RB has to be to get everything to fit together.